# Issue with argument in string resource, "0" replaced by "1" value

Tags: android

I have an issue on a specific project. I use argument in string resource.
I put a 0 value for argument but in app it shows 1 instead of 0.

I don't understand, I use this in others apps and it works well.

I set value for `TextView` only in 1 place in my code, and I see only 1 log in LogCat for each `TextView`.

In values.xml:

```
<string name="progress">%1$s %%</string>
<string name="record_progress">Record: %1$d / %2$d</string>
```

In activity:

```
Log.d(TAG,"nb record = " + records.size());
textViewRecord.setText(getString(R.string.record_progress, records.size(), 10));
Log.d(TAG,"progress = " + progress);
textViewProgress.setText(getString(R.string.progress, progress));
```

In LogCat:

```
D/MyApp(12673): nb record = 0
D/MyApp(12673): progress = 0
```

In app `textViewProgress` displayed "1 %" and `textViewRecord` displayed "Record: 1 / 10".

Comment: I just gave this a try and in my case my textviews display "0 %" and "Record 0 / 10" as expected.  So I think the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @EJK , I set value for textview only in 1 place in my code, and I see only 1 log for each textview.

Comment: My suggestion for you to solve this is to do the following: Strip down your app to the most minimal form necessary to reproduce the problem.  Remove everything that is not related to these 2 text views.  When done, you should have a single activity, 1 layout with 2 textviews, and 2 string resources.  If your problem still exists at that point, then at least you have a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) that you can post that will allow others to easily debug.